# Get value mapped to range of numbers using an integer to find the key in Rust

Tags: rust

In Rust, what is the simplest way I can select for a value mapped to a range of numbers, using an integer that lies within that range?

Something like:

```
range_values.insert(0..1000, "A");
range_values.insert(1001..2000, "B");

get_value(range_values, 1500); // returns "B"
```

Answer (score 4):

The *simplest* way is to use a vector of pairs and iterate through them sequentially to find the right entry in the vector.

```
use std::ops::Range;

fn get_value<'a>(range_values: &[(Range<i32>, &'a str)], key: i32) -> Option<&'a str> {
    for &(ref range, value) in range_values {
        //if range.contains(key) { // unstable as of Rust 1.23.0
        if (range.start <= key) && (key < range.end) {
            return Some(value);
        }
    }

    return None;
}

fn main() {
    let mut range_values = vec![];
    range_values.push((0..1000, "A"));
    range_values.push((1001..2000, "B"));

    println!("{:?}", get_value(&range_values, -1));   // prints None
    println!("{:?}", get_value(&range_values, 0));    // prints Some("A")
    println!("{:?}", get_value(&range_values, 500));  // prints Some("A")
    println!("{:?}", get_value(&range_values, 1000)); // prints None
    println!("{:?}", get_value(&range_values, 1500)); // prints Some("B")
    println!("{:?}", get_value(&range_values, 2500)); // prints None
}
```

However, it's not the most *efficient* way, especially as the vector gets larger. If the vector is sorted, then it's more efficient to perform a binary search (*O(log n)*) instead of a linear scan (*O(n)*). This assumes that the ranges don't overlap. (If the vector is not sorted and you only use it once, then it's faster to do a linear scan, since sorting is *O(n log n)*, i.e. slower than a single linear scan.)

```
use std::ops::Range;

fn get_value<'a>(range_values: &[(Range<i32>, &'a str)], key: i32) -> Option<&'a str> {
    // Find the index of the first item where `range.start <= key`.
    let index =
        match range_values.binary_search_by_key(&key, |&(ref range, _)| range.start) {
            Ok(index) => Some(index),

            // If the requested key is smaller than the smallest range in the slice,
            // we would be computing `0 - 1`, which would underflow an `usize`.
            // We use `checked_sub` to get `None` instead.
            Err(index) => index.checked_sub(1),
        };

    if let Some(index) = index {
        let (ref range, value) = range_values[index];
        if key < range.end {
            return Some(value);
        }
    }

    return None;
}

fn main() {
    let mut range_values = vec![];
    range_values.push((0..1000, "A"));
    range_values.push((1001..2000, "B"));

    // if the vector is not already sorted:
    range_values.sort_by_key(|&(ref range, _)| range.start);

    println!("{:?}", get_value(&range_values, -1));   // prints None
    println!("{:?}", get_value(&range_values, 0));    // prints Some("A")
    println!("{:?}", get_value(&range_values, 500));  // prints Some("A")
    println!("{:?}", get_value(&range_values, 1000)); // prints None
    println!("{:?}", get_value(&range_values, 1500)); // prints Some("B")
    println!("{:?}", get_value(&range_values, 2500)); // prints None
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Francis Gagné's idea of using binary search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48731081/155423), we can use a `BTreeMap` for the same purpose. This has the benefit of easier additions and removals without having to re-sort the list each time. Like the other answer, it only works for cases where the intervals are non-overlapping.

We need to construct a *newtype* around the `Range` to use the lower bound of the range as the key to look up by. We also wrap the `BTreeMap` to provide nicer access methods.

```
#![feature(inclusive_range_syntax)]

use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::{borrow, cmp}; 

fn main() {
    let mut range_values = RangeMap::default();

    range_values.insert(0..1000, "A");
    range_values.insert(1001..2000, "B");

    assert_eq!(range_values.get(-1),   None);
    assert_eq!(range_values.get(0),    Some(&"A"));
    assert_eq!(range_values.get(500),  Some(&"A"));
    assert_eq!(range_values.get(1000), None);
    assert_eq!(range_values.get(1500), Some(&"B"));
    assert_eq!(range_values.get(2500), None);
}

#[derive(Debug, Default, Clone)]
struct RangeMap<V>(BTreeMap<RangeKey, V>);

impl<V> RangeMap<V> {
    fn insert(&mut self, r: std::ops::Range<i32>, v: V) {
        self.0.insert(RangeKey(r), v);
    }

    fn get(&self, id: i32) -> Option<&V> {
        self.0.range(..=id).rev().next().and_then(|(k, v)| {
            // Recheck inside range
            if k.contains(id) {
                Some(v)
            } else {
                None
            }
        })
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Eq)]
struct RangeKey(std::ops::Range<i32>);

impl RangeKey {
    fn contains(&self, k: i32) -> bool {
        k >= self.0.start && k < self.0.end
    }

    fn key(&self) -> &i32 {
        &self.0.start
    }
}

impl PartialEq for RangeKey {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.key().eq(&other.key())
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for RangeKey {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<cmp::Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl Ord for RangeKey {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> cmp::Ordering {
        self.key().cmp(&other.key())
    }
}

impl borrow::Borrow<i32> for RangeKey {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &i32 {
        self.key()
    }
}
```

This unfortunately requires the not-yet-stable `RangeInclusive`.

For more complicated solutions, you will want an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are sequential starting with 0 like in your example, the simplest and most efficient way is simply to use a vector:

```
let mut range_values = vec!["A"; 1000];
range_values.append(&mut vec!["B"; 1000]);
assert_eq!(range_values[1500], "B");
```

If they are sequential but don't start with 0, you can still do it with a simple translation:

```
assert_eq!(range_values[1500 - start], "B");
```

If they are not sequential, then you need to use either [Francis Gagné's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48731081/5397009) or [Shepmaster's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48734046/5397009) answer.

Comment: Pedantically, the OP's question has *sequential* numbers, but not *continuous* ranges. For example, `1000` is included in **neither** of the ranges `0..1000` or `1001..2000`. This solution would return a value for 1000. This solution also takes up `O(N)` memory and requires that the key be able to be cloned / copied, so I'm not sure which measure of "most efficient" you are using.

Comment: "Most efficient" as in O(1) lookup time. Space efficiency depends on the size of the ranges in the real application: for long ranges yours of Francis' solution will be more efficient, but for short ranges direct indexing may still be the winner.

Comment: You're right that I missed the gap at 1000. If this gap is intentional and not a typo in the question then my solution looses some of its interest, although if there are only a few gaps those can be filled with canary values without incurring too high a memory cost and preserving the O(1) lookup times.